# With matched regex character, how can I get its uppercase equivalent?

Tags: javascript

The basic premise is I want to find a character following another and then replace that with its uppercase equivalent. I'm looking for a more elegant solution than `indexOf` and a for loop. I've got this far:

```
'this-is-my-string'.replace(/\-(\w)/,'$1')
```

which gives me `thisismystring` but I want `thisIsMyString`. Anything I can do to change `$1` into its uppercase equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use give replace a function as the second argument and whatever it returns will be used:

```
'this-is-my-string'.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(_, letter){
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [James Robert's toCamel string method](http://jamesroberts.name/blog/2010/02/22/string-functions-for-javascript-trim-to-camel-case-to-dashed-and-to-underscore/).

```
String.prototype.toCamel = function(){
    return this.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, function($1){return $1.toUpperCase().replace('-','');});
};
```

Then call it like:

```
'this-is-my-string'.replace(/\-(\w)/,'$1').toCamel();
```

Comment: The functionality is good but its generally a bad idea to augment built-in object prototypes.

Comment: @Trevor thanks for the advise. You have a good point when considering future compatibility. What if the next JS standard included a toCamel method, or the ever popular trim method (JavaScript 1.8.1)? Perhaps a supporting utility class would be a better alternative.

Comment: Yup, exactly. A simple, reusable function is sometimes all you need. ;)